Xray spectroscopy of elemental Cobalt
Can anyone please share the image of elemental cobalt Xray spectroscopy image? Particularly I would like to see how it shows within 50-200 eV range (or close to this range).
I have found some literatures, but they show Xray of Cobalt compounds (that is, different other molecules are attached to Cobalt). I am interested to see the Xray of pure Cobalt metal.
Please share references as well.
Thanks in advance.

I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs on Chemistry or Physics rather than Matter Modeling
